# How can I filter a Backbone collection down to all models with IDs that match any ID in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

I have an array of IDs like this:

```
var styles = ["600566", "600568", "600569", "600571", "600572", "600574", "600575", "600577", "600578", "600580"];
```

I have a collection called `Styles` with dozens of models, and I need to filter that collection down to the models that match an `id` in that array. I know I can find any model in a collection that matches an attribute to a single value like this:

```
var Selected_Styles = Styles.where({id: "600566"});
```

But I'm not sure how to match against multiple possible values.

Suggestions?

Comment: How about using the [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) function? For example something like `Styles.filter(function (s) { return styles.indexOf(s.id) != -1; });`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter and sort backbone collection with array of ids](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106843/filter-and-sort-backbone-collection-with-array-of-ids)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `_.filter` and `_.contains`:

```
Styles.filter(function(s) { return _.contains(styles, s.get('id')) });
```