# An Array to Backbone Collection

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

I think this is a simple question. It is based of this question.

[Filter and sort backbone collection with array of ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106843/filter-and-sort-backbone-collection-with-array-of-ids)

```
router.on('route:reportCollection', function(assetid) {

    var asset = assets.get(assetid);
    var reportpointers = asset.get('reportsid');

    var filteredReportCollection = new dilzeemQ.Collections.FilteredReportCollection({

    });

    ohhyearh = filteredReportCollection.filterById(reportpointers);

    var reportCollectionView = new dilzeemQ.Views.ReportCollection({
        collection: ohhyearh
    });

    console.log(ohhyearh);
    console.log(reports);


    $('#pagecontent').html(reportCollectionView.render().$el);
});
```

I have gotten it to work as I would like except the passing of the `collection : ohhyearh`

`ohhyearh` is something like this `[child,child]` where as I think it is expecting something along the lines of this `{child,child}`

Answer (score 1):

At the point where you pass `ohhyearh` to the view, it should be an `instanceof Backbone.Collection`. That is what the view is expecting, not an array or an object with a property for each child.

Based on the code in the snippet, I would say that your `filterById` function is probably doing something unexpected and not returning an actual collection. You can either modify it to `return new dilzeemQ.Collections.FilteredReportCollection(models)` or you can leave it as is, and create a new collection when you pass it to the view:

`collection: new dilzeemQ.Collections.FilteredReportCollection(ohhyearh)`

This is assuming that your `ohhyearh` object is an array with Backbone.Model instances. You can pass an array of models to a collection constructor to get a collection of those models.